# How to load value to textarea with php echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to load a value to an textarea.
I have the variable with the value on the php foreach on the top of the page, and I want to load it into a textarea.
Code from the foreach:

```
<?php
foreach($tasks as $cl)
{
    $cl_nome=$cl['nome'];
    $cl_data_nascimento=$cl['data_nascimento'];
    $cl_peso=$cl['peso'];
    $cl_altura=$cl['altura'];
    $cl_tipo_sangue=$cl['tipo_sangue'];
    $cl_alergias=$cl['alergias'];
    $cl_doencas=$cl['doencas'];
    $cl_telefone=$cl['telefone'];
    $cl_morada=$cl['morada'];
    $cl_notas=$cl['notas'];
    $cl_seguro=$cl['seguro'];
    $cl_identificador=$cl['identificador'];
}
?>
```

Code to the textarea:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea">Doenças:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="doencas" name="doencas" value="<?php echo $cl_doencas?>"></textarea>
  </div>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` does not have a value attribute, you load the data between the tags like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea">Doenças:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="doencas" name="doencas">
        <?php echo $cl_doencas; ?>
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the correct `textarea` code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="textarea">Doenças:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="doencas" name="doencas"><?php echo $cl_doencas; ?></textarea>
</div>
```